# Control.Invoke() gives an XML exception

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I am writing an application in C# that uses forms. This is my first app written in C# so I am very much a beginner.

This is the problematic code

```
if (tabControl1.InvokeRequired)
{
    stringDelegateC sdc = new stringDelegateC(manageCode);
    this.Invoke(sdc, new object[] { text });
}
else
...
```

The variable `text` is always a string in the format: "PM" followed by a number. It works fine most of the time but when `text` is "PM11020" I get `System.Xml.XmlException` thrown with the message "An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 5, position 25.". The exception is thrown by `this.Invoke(sdc, new object[] { text });`

If `text` is "PM11120", it works fine.

I am very confused by this, I don't know what XML has to do with anything.

Comment: Well what does `manageCode` do? And why have you introduced your own delegate type with an unconventional name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That XML exception is probably thrown by the `manageCode` method and has nothing related to `Control.Invoke`.